# Systemd service one shot service to be called on system startup and system shutdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspbian, systemd, raspberry-pi-zero

Here is my application to be run as a ssystemd service on a headless Pi system. It is a radio manager (written in python) for Bluetooth, Wifi and SSH).

On bootup check some IO pins:

```
if (bluetooth_gpio == HIGH):
rfkill unblock bluetooth
if (wifi_gpio == HIGH):
rfkill unblock wifi
#start SSH.service
```

And on Shutdown my service would do the following

```
rfkill block wifi
rfkill block bluetooth
#stop SSH.service
```

Is it better to run this as a one shot service with ExecStart and ExecStop commands OR a running service listening for Sigterm to run the shutdown steps

Thanks,

Comment: You don't ever need a running noop service; an ExecStopPost will trigger on shutdown even for a oneshot that was "started" by successfully executing a short-lived command (with RemainAfterExit true)

Comment: By the way, this type of question is usually more on-topic at our sister site [unix.se] than here. Stack Overflow is strictly scoped to questions about _writing code_; system administration is generally outside our range.

Comment: (also, we don't permit questions that are about best practice or opinion; "How can I fix this specific bug?" is great, "which of these two working approaches is best practice?" is unwelcome).

Comment: Thank you Charles for the tips and guidelines! I'll re-post my question on the Unix and Linux site